# Como hacer un enlace con PARAMETRO con RESOURCE

Tags: laravel, eloquent

¿Cual de las siguientes url sería la correcta **para pasar un parámetro** teniendo en cuenta que se utiliza Resource? Para contextualizarlo, en una página hay varios enlaces, y cada uno de ellos llevará a un contenido u otro: Animales, Casa, Saludos, Frutas. ¿Cómo indico el parámetro en el enlace? Al pulsar el enlace debe llevar al modelo el parámetro "animales" o "casa", etc.

```
<a href="{{ url('/encuestas',$categoria->animales) }}"></a>

<a href="{{ url('/encuestas',$categoria->'animales') }}"></a>

<a href="{{ route('/encuestas',$categoria->animales) }}"></a>

<a href="{{ route('/encuestas',$categoria->'animales') }}"></a>

{{ route('/encuestas')->parameters('categoria') }}
```

Teniendo en cueta que la rutas son,
La que contiene todas las preguntas:

```
Route::resource('/preguntas','PreguntaController');
```

Las que contiene el modelo index para mostrar el contenido filtrado por categoría:

```
Route::resource('/encuestas','EncuestaController');
```

La tabla que contiene preguntas con columna "categoria" para filtrar despues la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el método para consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en el controlador deberia ser `compact('preguntas´, categorias')`

Comment: y en si no logro comprender tu duda que tienes, solo quieres pasar un parametro dsde la url? si es asi esta podria ser una forma `{{ url('/admin/categories/'.$category->id) }}`

Comment: Gracias Dohko19. La duda es, cómo poner los enlaces. Por ejemplo en una web tengo varios enlaces que cada una representa una categoria de encuesta. Claro, cada uno de los enlaces debe ser diferente: "/encuesta/animales" o "/encuensta/saludos", etc. Mi duda es cómo poner los enlaces o url con Laravel utilizando controladores resource. Un saludo.

Comment: Bueno en la estructura de laravel al usar en las rutas `resource` se generan un listado de rutas por default que puedes ver por terminal utilizando `php artisan r:l` para llamar alguna ruta tendria que ser (ejemplo) `{{ route('mensajes.update', $message->id) }}`